# How to install /php-email-form/validate.js using npm

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use the validate.js from php-email-form but when I try to install it using "npm install php-email-form" it throws me an error. So what is the command to install that ???

Answer (score 0):

Your question it's a bit flat, we need to know, at least what error does it tell you?

Still, knowing only this, the [image: NPMJS.com] dictates that to install that library what you need is this other command:

`npm i php-form`